# Could not broadcast input array from shape (300,) into shape when mapping FastText word vectors with word in the dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, fasttext

I am working on creating a NLP model for my final year project. I am currently using Tensorflow Keras LSTM model to train the model. I have found a online guide for this as my dataset is in Sinhala but the code in that tutorial is old or has some issues. Currently when ever I runs

```
import fasttext
import fasttext.util

ft = fasttext.load_model("cc.si.300.bin")
ft.get_dimension()

# Mapping FastText word vectors with word in the dataset 
embeddings_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size+1, embedding_dim));
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = ft.get_word_vector(word)
    print(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embeddings_matrix[i] = embedding_vector;
```

I get the error below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-797ce5392360> in <cell line: 9>()
     11     print(word)
     12     if embedding_vector is not None:
---> 13         embeddings_matrix[i] = embedding_vector;

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (300,) into shape (16,)
```

As I am new to this, I don't know how to fix this issue exactly and I was not able to find a proper answer in the site too.

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing the values of `vocab_size` & `embedding_dim` that you're using to create your `embeddings_matrix`. (Also, at the time you're operating on it, `word_index` hasn't yet been established to hold any value.)

But, that seems like an error one might get trying to put a 300-dimensional vector into another array where it doesn't fit.

What are the values of `vocab_size` & `embedding_dim` – or equivalently what's `embeddings_matrix.shape` just before you get the error? If its 2nd dimension isn't `300`, it should be, and you should change your (unshown) code that sets up the controlling values to ensure that `embedding_matrix` is the right size.

(More foundationally, are you sure you need to copy each word's vector out of the `ft` model into your own matrix? You might not, depending on what you're planning to do next.)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the mistake i made. I am not knowledge enough to explain this but it seems the embedding_dim I defied earlier in the code doesn't support when it comes to the implementing the fasttext functionalities.

```
# Mapping FastText word vectors with word in the dataset 
embedding_dim = ft.get_dimension()
embeddings_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size+1, embedding_dim))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = ft.get_word_vector(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embeddings_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

Thank you for your help